# HTTPoison Multipart Post Request to Spree API

Tags: elixir, spree, httpoison

While attempting to post an image to Spree's [ProductImage API](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/api/product_images.html#create) using HTTPoison, it's failing with the Rails error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'permit' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f94fa150040>)`. The Elixir code that I'm using to generate this request is:

```
 def create() do
    data = [
      {:file, "42757187_001_b4.jpeg",
      {"form-data", [{"name", "image[attachment]"}, {"filename", "42757187_001_b4.jpeg"}]},
          [{"Content-Type", "image/jpeg"}]
        }, {"type", "image/jpeg"}
    ]

    HTTPoison.post!("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/1/images", {:multipart, data}, ["X-Spree-Token": "5d096ecb51c2a8357ed078ef2f6f7836b0148dbcc536dbfc", "Accept": "*/*"])
  end
```

I can get this to work using Curl with the following call:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -H "X-Spree-Token: 5d096ecb51c2a8357ed078ef2f6f7836b0148dbcc536dbfc" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  -F "image[attachment]=@42757187_001_b4.jpeg" \
  -F "type=image/jpeg" \
  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/1/images
```

For comparison, here's a RequestBin capture of both the failing HTTPoison request followed by the successful Curl request:
https://requestb.in/12et7bp1?inspect

What do I need to do in order to get HTTPoison to play nicely with this Rails API?

Comment: What if you add double quotes to name/filename values, like this: `[{"name", ~s|"image[attachment]"|}, {"filename", ~s|"42757187_001_b4.jpeg"|}]`?

Comment: @Dogbert That worked! For some reason didn't think those quotes were significant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Content-Disposition` line [requires double quotes around the `name` and `filename` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Syntax). `curl` adds those automatically but Hackney passes the data you specify as-is, so you need to add the double quotes to the values yourself.

This:

```
[{"name", "image[attachment]"}, {"filename", "42757187_001_b4.jpeg"}]
```

should be:

```
[{"name", ~s|"image[attachment]"|}, {"filename", ~s|"42757187_001_b4.jpeg"|}]
```

(I'm only using the `~s` sigil so that double quotes can be added without escaping them. `~s|""|` is exactly the same as `"\"\""`.)